# JsonGenerator appending json data to file without ovewriting

Tags: java, json, sockets, jackson

I am reading bytes from a socket and then writing to a json file using jsonGenerator. Problem is JsonGenerator is overwriting the file everytime a stream is received from the socket. how do I make it append the subsequent streams instead of overwriting?

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(
            new File("transactions.json"), JsonEncoding.UTF8);

            try {
        while ( (bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) != -1 ){ // -1 indicates EOF

            output= new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
            String length = output.substring(0, 4).trim();
            String mti = output.substring(4, 8).trim();
            String resp = "000";
            String newoutput = "";
            String bitmap = output.substring(8, 24);
            String stan = output.substring(24, 30);
            String date = output.substring(30, 44);
            String function_code = output.substring(44, 47);
            mti = "1814";


                // output to file

             generator.writeStartObject();
             generator.writeStringField("MTI", mti);
             generator.writeStringField("lenght", length);
             generator.writeStringField("stan", stan);
             generator.writeStringField("date", date);
             generator.writeStringField("Function Code", function_code);
                generator.writeEndObject();
           }
    } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exceptions "+e);
            }finally{
                generator.close();

            }
```

Also when I declare generator outside the while loop  and close it outside the loop for some reason the data is not written to the file so I am assuming the generator kinda like buffers it and when you close it writes to the file.

Comment: if you are writing multiple objects then they would be an array

Comment: Do you know that you should ensure that you read the whole message? In this code that you present it could read a half of message and try to process it, which will probably result in exception. You should have some protocol that reads the chunks of the inputStream from socket and process only whole chunks, not half-loaded.

Comment: You should close the generator in finally block, or use it in "try-with-resources" if you use java 1.7 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something in your question, but the overwriting reason that jumps out to me is that you aren't specifying that the file should be appended to. Most Java APIs (including Jackson) default to overwriting instead of appending.  The simple solution to this is just to use:

```
// the second parameter specifies whether the file should be appended
try(OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("transactions.json"), true)) {

    // pass the FileOutputStream to the generator instead
    JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(fos , JsonEncoding.UTF8);
}
```

I would leave it at that for my answer, but I would be remiss if I didn't point out that if you are reading from multiple sockets concurrently, then you are probably going to end up with JSON data written interleaved.

I suggest wrapping the method in a synchronize block of some sort to prevent this and make it thread-safe.

Below I have an example of how I would re-write this functionality.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonEncoding;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

/**
 * A thread-safe class that will append JSON transaction data to a file.
 */
public class TransactionWriter {
    private static final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();

    /**
     * Helper method that will read a number of UTF8 characters from an input stream and return them in a string.
     *
     * @param inputStream stream to read from
     * @param charsToRead number of characters to read
     * @return string of read characters
     * @throws IOException when unable to read enough characters from the stream
     */
    private static String readUtf8Chars(InputStream inputStream, int charsToRead) throws IOException {
        // since we know this is UTF8 up front, we can assume one byte per char
        byte[] buffer = new byte[charsToRead];

        // fill the buffer
        int readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer);

        // check that the buffer was actually filled
        if(readBytes < charsToRead)
            throw new IOException("less bytes available to read than expected: " + readBytes + " instead of " + charsToRead);

        // create a string from the buffer
        return new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }


    private final File file;
    private final Object writeLock = new Object();

    /**
     * Constructs a new instance for an output file.
     *
     * @param file file to append to
     */
    public TransactionWriter(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    /**
     * Reads a transaction from the input stream and appends a JSON representation to this instance's output file.
     *
     * @param inputStream stream to read from; will be closed after this method is closed
     * @throws IOException when reading or writing failed
     */
    public void write(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // since we have multiple threads appending to the same file, synchronize to prevent concurrency issues
        synchronized(writeLock) {

            // open the output stream to append to the file
            try(FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {

                // create the generator for the output stream
                JsonGenerator generator = jsonFactory.createGenerator(outputStream, JsonEncoding.UTF8);

                // write the data to the generator
                generator.writeStartObject();
                generator.writeStringField("length", readUtf8Chars(inputStream, 4).trim());
                generator.writeStringField("MTI", readUtf8Chars(inputStream, 4).trim());
                String bitmap = readUtf8Chars(inputStream, 16);
                generator.writeStringField("stan", readUtf8Chars(inputStream, 8));
                generator.writeStringField("date", readUtf8Chars(inputStream, 14));
                generator.writeStringField("Function Code", readUtf8Chars(inputStream, 3));
                generator.writeEndObject();

            } finally {
                // output stream is closed in try-with-resources, but also close the input stream
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***To be clear, I have not tested this code at all. I simply know that it compiles on Java 7 language level.***

Comment: thanks. let me try your option. but I am reading from one socket and also its only that I havent put the full code in here, I am using threads when a stream comes a new thread is spawned executes then kills it. but i will finally refine it with multithreaded server where i will have worker threads. for now i just want the logic to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the generator outside the loop (before the loop).

take the loop in `try-catch` statement, there are two options:

You should close the generator (after the loop) in finally block, or use it in "`try-with-resources`" way if you use `java 1.7`

Additionally, do you know that you should ensure that you read the whole message? In this code that you present it could read a half of message and try to process it, which will probably result in exception. You should have some protocol that reads the messages of the `inputStream` from socket and process only whole messages, not half-loaded chunks. – Krzysztof Cichocki 2 mins ago   edit

Comment: I have tried your idea but still doesn't work its not writing anything to the file immediately the generator.close is taken out of the loop

Comment: maybe try to move  generator.writeStartObject(); and generator.writeEndObject(); also outside the loop?